# Wcf Service intermittently blocks while Http File POST is running in IFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3

```
This program has 2 components: 
     1. an HTML page containing 
       A- an  that contains a file upload
       B- javascript running in the containing page that is 
          on a 1-second timer to make a wcf call to get progress statistics.
     2. a Wcf Service that is contacted by the javascript every second.
```

The file uploads to an MVC3 Controller action which reads the data in 100kb chunks, and updates a Percent Complete statistic in a singleton Hashtable (or Dictionary) as it progresses.

Meanwhile, the Wcf Service (#2 above) retrieves the statistic from the singleton and returns it as JSON.

PROBLEM:
After a fresh deployment, everything works!   I can upload a file from two different browsers at the same time, and watch the progress increment from 0% to 100% in each browser.   But, at some time later, the Wcf Services starts blocking.   Using Fiddler, I can see the javascript GET requests  are being sent, but no response comes.   The javascript might issue 10 of these before the file upload completes, at which time all 10 responses finally come back, and they all say 100%, which means the code in the Wcf Service was blocked at (or before) trying to access the singleton hashtable.

Note: At first, I was trying to use Session state to store the progress value and retrieve it from the Wcf, but I learned that the Session state for a given SessionId cannot be accessed concurrently by two threads (ie by my action thread and by the Wcf thread), so I switched it to use a static singleton. I've tried both Hashtable and Dictionary<> as the singleton because of their varying thread safety.

What is puzzling is that it works very well for awhile, then hours later when I test, it is exhibiting the blocking behavior again.

Note: This is deployed to a GoDaddy Windows 4GH Shared Host.  But the same behavior occurs when I deploy to a local IIS 7.5 instance.

```
The Wcf Service:
      AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
     [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
     public class OnoService : IOnoService
       . . .
     public UploadProgress GetUploadProgress(string controlid)
     {
        UploadProgress up = new UploadProgress();
        up.PercentComplete = SharedState.GetValue(controlid) as string;
        return up;
     }



The Containing page: Index.cshtml
    <divid="progressdiv"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="@Session.SessionID" name="controlId" id="controlId"/>
    <iframe src="UploadForm"/>

The IFrame UploadForm
      <form action="@Url.Content("~/MemberArea/UploadImage")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         OwnerId <input type="text" id="ownerId" name="ownerId"   />
         <input type="hidden" value="@Session.SessionID" name="controlId" id="controlId"/>
         Image File <input type="file" id="image" name="image" />
         <input type="submit" />
      </form>

The Javascript:
       $(function () {
         monitorProgress();
       });

    function monitorProgress() {
      var controlId = $("#controlId").val();
      var url = "Services/OnoService.svc/GetUploadProgress/"+controlId;
      $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            var items = [];
            var result =data.GetUploadProgressResult.PercentComplete + " %";
            $("#progressdiv").text(result);
      });
      setTimeout("monitorProgress()", 1000);   
    }


A few excerpts from web.config:

     &ltsessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false" />
    . . .
       &ltsystem.webServer>
          &ltstaticContent>
             &ltclientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
          &lt/staticContent>
    . . .
          &ltbehaviors>
             &ltserviceBehaviors>
                &ltbehavior name="">
                   &ltserviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                   &ltserviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                &lt/behavior>

SharedState.cs:
    public class SharedState
    {

        private static Hashtable store = null;
        private static Hashtable GetDictionary()
        {
            if (null == store)
                store = new Hashtable();
            return store;
        }

        public static void StoreValue(string key, object value)
        {
            GetDictionary()[key] = value;
        }
        public static object GetValue(string key)
        {
            if (GetDictionary().ContainsKey(key))
                return GetDictionary()[key];
            return null;
        }
    }
```

So, does anyone have any insight as to why the Wcf Service would be blocking after it has been running correctly for several concurrent attempts?

Comment: `I've tried both Hashtable and Dictionary<> as the singleton because of their varying thread safety` - erm, not sure about thread safety you are talking here since both those structures are **not** thread safe so you should synchronize access to them. Also is the WCF service sole purpose to return a JSON with the progress? I mean there are so many other and easier things to do, like using a client scripting upload component such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) for example.

Comment: Hi Darin - Thanks ... It's not just this specific problem I am worried about, this is something that should work, I am going to want to employ this technique in alot of other solutions besides just File Uploads.  So I'd really like to get to the bottom of this issue.